# Creating Agent and Running every 60 sec. in bitrix24

Tags: php, agent, bitrix

I have added one function in timeman mosule as follows.

```
class CTimeManReport extends CAllTimeManReport
{

   function testAgent()
   {
    mail('t@demo.co.in','agent','agent');
    return "testAgent();";
   }


}
```

Now I want to run this function every 60 sec.I have added agent though control panel in agent section,but its running only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running the agent bitrix added to database value that agent function returns. So in your case, it must be `return "CTimeManReport::testAgent();"` because your function is a class method.

Also, it must be a class method, not an instance method, so add `public static` before your function

So, try to do something like that:

```
class CTimeManReport extends CAllTimeManReport
{

   public static function testAgent()
   {
    mail('t@demo.co.in','agent','agent');
    return "CTimeManReport::testAgent();";
   }
}
```

If this advice doesn't help, you can add cron support for your agents, because by default they work on pages reloads. Follow [this link](https://training.bitrix24.com/support/training/course/?COURSE_ID=12&LESSON_ID=6603) for instructions

P.S. don't add your own code into the bitrix module's code. Because you may lose your code after bitrix updates. Add your own code or include your classes into the `local/php_interface/init.php`

Comment: thanks for your help. Can you provide me example code for php.ini as per my agent

Comment: You don't need to change the php.ini, you have to change the `dbconn.php`, create `cron_events.php` and add this script to the `cron`. [All insturctions here](https://training.bitrix24.com/support/training/course/?COURSE_ID=12&LESSON_ID=6603)

Comment: Sorry I mean init.php not php.ini typo mistek

Comment: So, ok) `init.php` helps you to include your additional classes, functions, and constants to the bitrix and use them everywhere in components, classes, templates and etc. And you can add your class or function straight to the init.php, or you can create a new file and `require` it in the init.php. Also, you can create the folder and add autoloader (`spl_autoload_register`) to the init.php, it helps you to include all your classes from folder to the bitrix